# How to resolve linker path error when using home-brew clang 13 in CMake project on macOS 12

Tags: macos, cmake, clang

In order to make use of newer C++ 17 and 20 features, I want to switch from Apple clang to a homebrew installed vanilla clang. I installed it via `brew install llvm`.

When trying to build a minimal CMake based test project like

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -G Ninja testProject
```

CMake fails with

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 13.0.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 13.0.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang - broken
CMake Error at /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /Users/me/Projects/testProject/build/CLion/Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/local/bin/ninja cmTC_d2d4b && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d2d4b.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_d2d4b
    FAILED: cmTC_d2d4b 
    : && /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/cmTC_d2d4b.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_d2d4b   && :
    ld: library not found for -lSystem
    clang-13: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

So it seems that it fails to locate the correct library search path out of the box.

When trying to build a simple hello world program from the command line like

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ main.cpp -isysroot /Library/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk
```

It fails with even not finding some headers.

Supplying the header and library search path explicitly to the build command like

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ main.cpp -I"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include" -L"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib"
```

makes it work. However, both are no solutions to make the built-in CMake compiler check work and they don't seem like the correct way to go.

Once this is working correctly, I'm furthermore interested in being able to compile ObjectiveC++ code which currently fails with even more errors.

I think I understand the problem that the compiler does not know the correct search paths, but I'm lacking some understanding about how it would normally figure out those search paths in a CMake project.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get it working by supplying a few linker flags through the `LDFLAGS` environment variable:

`-L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/usr/lib`
In order to find the system libraries needed by the C compiler check

`-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib`
In order to find the C++ libraries as needed by the C++ compiler check

In order to successfully compile Objective-C code that links to Apple frameworks, I furthermore needed to add
`-F/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -lobjc`

With those flags, I now can successfully build my projects. Still, I'm not 100% sure if this is the right way, especially if the libraries linked from `/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib` can be expected to be present on all target systems?